# file uploading with php xml

Tags: php, xml

i have some problem with this code.
The problem is about the upload part of the script, when the user save the information, the file won't be uploaded by the script. Maybe i've made some errors?
The xml file work correctly, and any new inserted information are saved. i have two file input to separate the files.. i think the issue is related to this..?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['savetrack'])){

 $errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['audio_file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $Audiofile_name = $key.$_FILES['audio_file']['name'][$key];
    $Audiofile_size =$_FILES['audio_file']['size'][$key];
    $Audiofile_tmp =$_FILES['audio_file']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $Audiofile_type=$_FILES['audio_file']['type'][$key];

    $audioextensions = array("mp3");

$Audiofile_ext=explode('.',$_FILES['audio_file']['name'][$key]) ;
$Audiofile_ext=end($Audiofile_ext);  
$Audiofile_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['audio_file']['name'][$key])));  
if(in_array($Audiofile_ext,$audioextensions ) === false){
$errors[]="extension not allowed";
}            

    if($file_size > 50097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 50 MB';
    }       
    $desired_dir="mp3";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$Audiofile_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($Audiofile_tmp,"mp3/".$Audiofile_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="mp3/".$Audiofile_name.time();
             rename($Audiofile_tmp,$new_dir) ;  
        }           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
```

// Cover upload

```
foreach($_FILES['cover_file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $Imgfile_name = $key.$_FILES['cover_file']['name'][$key];
    $Imgfile_size =$_FILES['cover_file']['size'][$key];
    $Imgfile_tmp =$_FILES['cover_file']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $Imgfile_type=$_FILES['cover_file']['type'][$key];

    $imgextensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");

    $Imagefile_ext=explode('.',$_FILES['cover_file']['name'][$key]) ;
$Imagefile_ext=end($Imgfile_ext);  
$Imagefile_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['cover_file']['name'][$key])));  
if(in_array($Imgfile_ext,$imgextensions ) === false){
$errors[]="extension not allowed";
}

    if($Imgfile_size > 50097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 50 MB';
    }       
    $desired_imgdir="img";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir("$desired_imgdir/".$Imgfile_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($Imgfile_tmp,"img/".$Imgfile_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $imgnew_dir="img/".$Imgfile_name.time();
             rename($Imgfile_tmp,$imgnew_dir) ; 
        }           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}  

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('tracks.xml');

$filenameAudio = $_FILES['audio_file']['name']; 

$element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('track')->item(0);

$artistname = $element->getElementsByTagName('artist')->item(0);
$tracktitle = $element->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
$relyear = $element->getElementsByTagName('year')->item(0);
$relabel = $element->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0);
$cover = $element->getElementsByTagName('cover')->item(0);    
$audio = $element->getElementsByTagName('audio')->item(0);

$newItem = $xml->createElement('track');
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('artist',      $_POST['artist_name']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('title', $_POST['track_title']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('year', $_POST['year']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('label',    $_POST['record_label']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('cover',$Imgfile_name));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('audio',$Audiofile_name));
$xml->getElementsByTagName('releases')->item(0)->appendChild($newItem);
$xml->save('tracks.xml');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by using an upload class and it seems to work. Now the issue is to load the uploaded audio file where i need, the consolle give me the following errors:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
GET http://localhost:8810/mixtape/mp3/audiofile 404 (Not Found)

I don't know if this issue is because the file name is loaded from a tag saved into the xml or if there is another type of problem. If i insert the file location manually it will work, but i need to load it from the xml.

here is the html code where i need to load the mp3 file, i've inserted the path where uploaded mp3 are hosted, but unsuccessfully.

```
<ul class="grid">
<?php
try{
$xml=simplexml_load_file("tracks.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create    object");
}catch (Exception $e){
echo $e;
} 
foreach($xml as $child)
{
$artistname = $child->artist;
$tracktitle = $child->title;
$relyear = $child->year;
$label = $child->label;
$audiofile = $child->audio;
$coverfile = $child->cover;
?>
<li class="grid__item">     
<a class="grid__link" href="#album" data-playlist-1="mp3/<?php echo  $audiofile ?>" data-playlist-2="mp3/<?php echo $audiofile ?>"> 
<div class="img-wrap img-wrap--grid">
<svg class="lp lp--grid">
<use xlink:href="#icon-lp-mini"></use>
</svg>
<img class="img img--grid" src="img/<?php echo $coverfile ?>" alt="album cover" />
</div>
<span class="year"><?php echo $relyear ?></span>
<h2 class="artist"><?php echo $artistname ?></h2>
<h3 class="title"><?php echo $tracktitle ?></h3>
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```